# Spring 5 - Chain reactive webclient calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm trying to learn how to use the reactive WebClient in Spring 5.
Let's say I have 3 calls I need to make:

1. Get an access token
2. Get a list of accounts
3. For each account, get a list of transactions.

Here, calls 2 and 3 each depend on the output of 1, whilst 3 also depends on the output of 2.

I know I can do something like:

```
accessTokenService
    .getAccessToken()
    .flatMapMany(accountsService::getAccounts)
    ...
```

But any subsequent calls to `flatMap` or `doOnNext` (or anything else) only have access to the accounts, not the access token.

My question I think boils down to:

If call 2 depends on the output of call 1, and call 3 depends on the output of calls 1 & 2, is there a standard way to accomplish this without having to use `block()`?

Edit for clarification: Call 3 requires the output of call 1 an input, and also the output of call 2 as input, e.g.:

```
accessTokenService
    .getAccessToken() // Call 1
    .flatMapMany((accessToken) -> accountsService.getAccounts(accessToken)) // Call 2
    .flatMapMany((accessToken, accounts) -> transactionService.getTransactions(accessToken, accounts)) // Call 3
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data classes `Account`, `Token` and `Transaction`, and the following service layer structure:

```
interface AccessTokenService {
    Mono<Token> getAccessToken();
}
interface AccountsService {
    Flux<Account> getAccounts(Token token);
}
interface TransactionService {
    Flux<Transaction> getTransactions(Token token, Flux<Account> account);
}
```

Then you can get all the transactions together for all accounts after receiving the token this way:

```
Flux<Transaction> transactions = accessTokenService
    .getAccessToken()
    .flatMapMany(token -> {
        final Flux<Account> accounts = accountsService.getAccounts(token);
        return transactionService.getTransactions(token, accounts);
    });
```

Note that all of the calls above are non-blocking.

What happens next with the transactions `Flux` is left to you:

- You can block the first/last result.
- You can return them all through the REST controller.
- You can let them all consume it by a subscriber or R2DBC, you name it.

Comment: The problem here is that `accountService.getTransactions` also requires the access token to make the call.

Comment: Update the question. Nobody knows what your code looks like. I will edit my answer, but until then, I can help only based on assumptions. Make your question clear, first.

Comment: I've added a little clarification at the bottom. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I have edited the answer. It is still unclear whether the method `transactionService.getTransactions` accepts aside from the `Token` a `List` or `Flux` of accounts. Provide the method interfaces for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it using:

1. Reactor [Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context.api), since version `3.1.3`.
2. Reactor [Tuple](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/function/Tuple2.html).
3. Create a wrapper object which contains data && access token.